# Setup file installs DLLs

Tags: mit, gpl-2, license, microsoft

I have a Windows Forms Project written in C++ CLI with MySQL Database integration. I have created a Setup File using INNO Setup but I need to include MySQL.Data.dll to deploy the application, so should I provide any license for it like GPL2 or something.

Also if I upload my source code on GitHub, but only Source Files and Project files(.sln, .vcxproj etc) are uploaded then what License should I use for it.

I believe for GitHub part I can use MIT License since Windows Forms has become Open Source and also I am not providing any .dll in repo

For Setup File I believe that I do not need to add any license for it

PS. This is a college Project but I need to follow all good and ethical practices